# trying to read a sentence from user and write in text file

Tags: c

I'm trying to create something where I need to receive a sentence from the user and it is then written in a text file. I know how to do this with integers and float but it doesn't seem to work with char.

```
main()
{
    unsigned char word;
    FILE *f;
    errno_t err;
    printf("Enter Text: ");
    scanf_s("%c", &word);
    err = fopen_s(&f, "testwrite.txt", "w");
    fprintf_s(f, "%c", word);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `scanf_s` is **not** a direct replacement for `scanf`, and the call is missing one argument, which the compiler should **warn** you about. *"Unlike `scanf` ... `scanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."* And the code only inputs a single character, not a 'sentence'.

Comment: By the way, the format `%c` is for *single characters* not for words or "sentences".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But `word`, confusingly, IS a `char`.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, it seems the OP have some misunderstandings.

Comment: @2Senya1 - How do you define _sentence_?

Comment: i definitely have some misunderstandings. im exremely new to c programming. by sentences I mean for example "Johnson and Johnson" or even just a word like "America" (which is not sentence lol). if %c if used for a single character, what do I use for lots of words?

Comment: also i dont recieve errors, when i input a word it only shows the first letter in the text file, which makes more sense now since %c is for a single character.

Comment: You have two choices: (1) use `fgets` instead of `scanf`; (2) use `scanf` and `%[^\n]`.  I recommend (1).  The only reason to use `scanf` is that it's nice & easy, but `%[...]` ceases to be nice & easy.

Comment: none of its working......i dont know what im doing wrong. I just need a program that will scan inputs from users and print whatever was scanned onto a text file. ive tried it with integers and floats and it works but i cant seem to get it to work with text. any help?

Answer (score -1):

to get input from the user:

```
char input[1000];
scanf("%s", input);
```

and to write it to a file:

```
fputc(input, f);
```

and the final piece code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char input[1000];

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(fileName ,"w+");

    printf("enter text:");
    scanf("%s", input);

    fputc(input, f);

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The original poster wants the ability to read sentences possibly containing spaces, which `%s` very much won't do.